# Как получить текущий пункт используя ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

У меня есть HTML код с `ng-click`:

```html
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends">
<div ng-click="friend.blocked = true"></div>
</div>
```

Как мне заменить его на:

```js
ng-click="get()"
```

и выполнить эту операцию в функции get():

```js
$scope.get = function (){
  friend.blocked = true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно передать этот объект в нужную функцию в качестве параметра.

HTML:

```
ng-click="get(friend)"
```

JS:

```
$scope.get = function (friend){
    friend.blocked = true;
}
```